# Chrome touchenter touchleave

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, touch

I've seen this question asked a couple times on here but no one has replied.

Before I go implementing the more resource intensive elementAtPoint method, can someone confirm that Chrome does not support `touchenter` and `touchleave` events?

The MDN documents it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchenter

The latest W3C draft specifies it http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/

Does anyone know if any of the Chrome versions support it, even if it's in development, can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, pretty outdated I guess... Anyways, I've just used touch events, they are supported now, and Chrome will eventually emit touch events instead of clicking if you switch to device mode on the developer window (F12). Thus they are kinda easy to test.

CanIUse is also a friend: http://caniuse.com/#search=touch